# Get .text() value when using nested $(this) statements

Tags: jquery, function

When clicking an `<a>` tag, I want to take the text value of said link and place it inside of another `<div>` (`.current-selection`) within the parent. However, I also need to `fadeOut()` the parent to allow this change to happen out of sight, before bringing it back with `fadeIn()`. I can get this to work individually, but not when placing the text change within the fadeOut() function.

The code below gets the text of the parent, rather than the originally clicked  tag. What can I do differently when nesting like this?

Thank you.

```
$('.filter').on( 'click', 'a', function() {
    // Fadeout text to allow for hidden text change
    $(this).parent.fadeOut(function() {

        // Change text of the current selection to match the item just clicked (not working)
        $('.filter').find('.current-selection').text($(this).text());   

    }).fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: Why not just store the value before entering the callback?

Comment: Read up on $(this) - the one in parent.fadeOut() refers to the parent element, not the anchor element referred to by $(this) in the onclick. As per @Rich point, use something like var theAnchor = $(this); before you call the fadeOut() function and replace the reference to $(this) in the fadeOut() function. Et voila.

Comment: Thanks @VanquishedWombat - helpful starting point which got it resolved. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put the text in an extra  variable

```
$('.filter').on( 'click', 'a', function() {
    var value = $(this).html();
    $(this).parent().fadeOut(function() {
        $('.filter .current-selection').text(value);   

    }).fadeIn();
});
```